# Factoring quartic equation

Tags: factoring

$$x^4+6x^2+25=0$$

How could I factor it into $(x^2-2x+5)(x^2+2x+5)=0$?

I got the result looking into horrible formulas on wikipedia, but I suppose there's a much easier way. Could you help me?

Comment: **Complete the square** $\,\color{#c00}5^2+ (\color{#0a0}{x^2})^2$ by adding  $\ 2(\color{#c00}5\color{#0a0}{x^2})\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\underbrace{(x^2)^2+5^2+2\cdot x^2\cdot5}+(6-10)x^2=(x^2+5)^2-(2x)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply replace $x^2$ by $y$. You then end with a quadratic equation in $y$ from which later uou could extract $x$. The solutions of the quadratic are $-3-4 i$ and $-3+4 i$. Taking the square roots, you then obtain $$x=-1 - 2 I$$ $$x=-1 + 2 I$$ $$x=1 - 2 I$$  $$x=1 - 2 I$$.

Comment: Well, that's not that easy taking square roots if you don't know exponential representation :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$
x^4+6x^2+25=(x^4+6x^2+9)+16=(x+3)^2+4^2=(x^2+3+4i)(x^2+3-4i) \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{C}.
$$
Let $u \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $u^2=3+4i$. It is easy to show that $u\in\{2+i,-2-i\}$. We have
\begin{eqnarray}
x^4+6x^2+25&=&(x^2+u^2)(x^2+\bar{u}^2)=(x+iu)(x-iu)(x+i\bar{u})(x-i\bar{u})\\
&=&(x+iu)\overline{(x+iu)}(x-iu)\overline{(x-iu)}\\
&=&|x+iu|^2|x-iu|^2=|x-1+2i|^2|x+1-2i|^2\\
&=&[(x-1)^2+4][(x+1)^2+4]=(x^2-2x+5)(x^2+2x+5).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: but how do you know that u=+- (2+i)?